# How to set two animation listeners for same Animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am wondering if there is any way to set two listeners for the same animation object.

I tried to set two animation listeners but the one which I had put first only getting called. The second listener is ignored.

Comment: please post your code so that we can help

Comment: Call another listener from the listener which is set to animation object.

Comment: Well, it is "setAnimationListener" and not "addAnimationListener". This indicates that only one at a time is possible. Can't you use just one listener? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [Animators](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) rather than Animations which actually do have `addListener` methods.

Aside from that, the way you assign multiple listeners is to have a listener that holds other listeners and sends the messages to them.

```
public interface Listener {
   void onEvent();
}

public class CompoundListener implements Listener {

    private final Collection<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener lis) {
        listeners.add(lis);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener lis) {
        listeners.remove(lis);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
       for(Listener lis : listeners) {
          lis.onEvent();
       }
    }
}
```

Then just set the `CompoundListener` to the main listener and assign all other Listeners to the `CompoundListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick would be

```
class ListenerWrapper implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    private List<Animation.AnimationListener> listeners;

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        for (Animation.AnimationListener listener : listeners)
            listener.onAnimationStart(animation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
}
```

.. Etc

And do the same for the rest of the callbacks